# How can I increment a file reference in data-src?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a page where when I click the img the number in the data-src attribute will increase by 1. So I can number my images 1 to whatever or perhaps have an arrow either side of the image, one that will increase by one and one that will decrease by one to create a slideshow?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/gif-zoomer.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/gif-zoomer.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="zoomer-loading">loading <span class="spinner"></span></div>
    <div class="zoomer-img" data-src="img/1.gif"></div></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _" when I click the img"_ `img` element not appear at `html` at Question ? See also closing `</a>` tag , without opening `<a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
$('zoomer-img').click(function(){
    var that =     $(this);
    var num = parseInt(that.data('src').substring(that.data('src').indexOf('img/'),that.lastIndexOf('.'))) + 1;
    that.data('src','img/'+num+'.gif');
});
```

You can increment by getting the number in the data-src attr.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the counter in a different attribute so you dont have to parse the data-src every time

```
<div class="zoomer-img" data-src="img/1.gif" data-counter="1"></div>
```

Then jQuery:

```
$(".zoomer-img").click(function(){
    var counter = parseInt($(this).data("counter"));
    counter++;
    $(this).attr("data-counter",counter)
           .attr("data-src","img/"+counter+".gif");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.replace()`

```js
$(".zoomer-img").click(function() {
  $(this).data("src", $(this).data("src").replace(/(\d+)/, function(m) {
    return 1 + Number(m)
  }))
  $(this).html($(this).data().src)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zoomer-loading">loading <span class="spinner"></span>
</div>
<div class="zoomer-img" data-src="img/1.gif">click</div>
```